# Updating a lot of rows with random data in Mysql

Tags: mysql, random, sql-order-by

I have a database with personal data that I want to anonymize with random names etc. Eg., the table `person (id int, first_name varchar, last_name varchar, birth_date date)`. I also have a table with random names, eg. `first_name (id int, value varchar)`. I know that this boils down to optimizing `select * from ... order by rand()` and I've read several StackOverflow questions on it (and http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/), but this doesn't answer the question of updating with random data in bulk.

I've tried:

1. (Initially) `UPDATE _person me SET birth_date = (SELECT value FROM anonymizer.birth_date ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)` (...same for other columns). As there are multiple tables, anonymizing the whole DB was going for an hour when I interrupted it.
2. (Currently) `UPDATE _person me join anonymizer.first_name on anonymizer.first_name.id = round(rand() * (select max(id) from anonymizer.first_name)) SET first_name = anonymizer.first_name.value`. This single query took 5 minutes (apart from other columns and tables).

I can prepare my fake data tables in any way (init with sequence numbers etc.). Is there a way to anonymize the DB efficiently?

Comment: What are you requirements here?  Are you aware that both of your current methods could assign the same random name to more than one record in your `person` table?

Comment: This is not a problem. The original values have to be erased, the outcome should be a completely anonymized database, it may contain duplicates.